# R foreach: from single-machine to cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, snow, parallel-foreach

The following (simplified) script works fine on the master node of a unix cluster (4 virtual cores).

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

nc = detectCores()
cl = makeCluster(nc)
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i = 1:nrow(data_frame_1), .packages = c("package_1","package_2"), .export = c("variable_1","variable_2"))  %dopar% {     

    row_temp = data_frame_1[i,]
    function(argument_1 = row_temp, argument_2 = variable_1, argument_3 = variable_2)

}

stopCluster(cl)
```

**I would like to take advantage of the 16 nodes in the cluster (`16 * 4` virtual cores in total).**

I guess all I need to do is change the **parallel backend** specified by [`makeCluster`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/makeCluster.html). But how should I do that? The documentation is not very clear.

Based on this quite old (2013) post http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-wonders-of-foreach/ it seems that I should change the default type (`sock` or `MPI` - which one- would that work on unix?)

**EDIT**

From this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf) by the authors of foreach:

> By default, doParallel uses multicore functionality on Unix-like
>   systems and snow functionality on Windows.  Note that the multicore
>   functionality only runs tasks on a single computer, not a cluster of
>   computers.  However, you can use the snow functionality to execute on
>   a cluster, using Unix-like operating systems, Windows, or  even a
>   combination.

What does `you can use the snow functionality` mean? How should I do that?

Comment: I am not using a for loop...

Comment: I would recommend downloading Revolution R open, which has improved statistical libraries and multi-core support. [check my answer on this post for more information about RRO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900708/how-can-i-get-r-to-use-more-cpu-usage/33996564#33996564). This is not directly related to your question, but it will speed up any mathematical calculations and package which can use multi cores.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `parallel` package is a merger of the `multicore` and `snow` packages, but if you want to run on multiple nodes, you have to make use of the "snow functionality" in `parallel` (that is, the part of `parallel` that was derived from `snow`). Practically speaking, that means you need to call `makeCluster` with the "type" argument set to either "PSOCK", "SOCK", "MPI" or "NWS" because those are the only cluster types supported by the current version of `parallel` that support execution on multiple nodes. If you're using a cluster that is managed by knowledgeable HPC sysadmins, you should use "MPI", otherwise it may be easier to use "PSOCK" (or "SOCK" if you have a particular reason to use the "snow" package).

If you choose to create an "MPI" cluster, you should execute the script via R using the `mpirun` command with the "-n 1" option, and the first argument to `makeCluster` set to the number of workers that should be spawned. (If you don't know what that means, you may not want to use this approach.)

If you choose to create a "PSOCK" or "SOCK" cluster, the first argument to `makeCluster` must be a vector of hostnames, and `makeCluster` will start workers on those nodes via the "ssh" command when `makeCluster` is executed. That means you must have ssh daemons running on all of the specified hosts.

I've written much more on this subject elsewhere, but hopefully this will help you get started.

Comment: it was a pain to install the `Rmpi` package but I finally succeeded. When I follow the recommendation from the answer below and create the parallel backend with `makeCluster(16, type = "MPI")` the R session is terminated and I get a seg fault error (on the linux shell). So it seems that the only way to make it work is to use `mpirun` as you said but that seems complicated

Comment: @Antoine If R seg faults, I would guess that Rmpi isn't correctly installed. Did you try using a PSOCK cluster with a vector of hostnames, or did you run into ssh problems?

Comment: @Antoine You *have* to execute your R script via mpirun if you want to use multiple nodes using Rmpi. If you execute `makeCluster(16, type = "MPI")` from your R script without using mpirun, all 16 workers will start on the local machine. I suppose that could even be the cause of the seg fault.

Comment: hum I see. thanks much for the feedback I will try to learn how to use `mpirun`

Comment: @Antoine If you're using Open MPI (which I recommend for Rmpi), you can use a command such as `mpirun -n 1 -H "localhost,n1,n2" R --slave -f script.R` where "n1" and "n2" are legal hostnames. This causes mpirun to execute your script only on "localhost", but enables Rmpi to spawn workers on hosts "n1" and "n2" as well. Start with some simple tests, such as using `makeCluster(2, type="MPI")`.

Comment: thank you very much this is very helpful! Let me try, I'll keep you posted

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer that may send you in the right direction

> Based on this quite old (2013) post
>   http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-wonders-of-foreach/ it seems that I
>   should change the default type (fork to MPI but why? would that work
>   on unix?)

`fork` is a way of spawning background processes on POSIX system. on a single node with `n` cores, you can spawn `n` processes in parallel and do work. this doesn't work across multiple machines as they don't share memory. you need a way to get data between them.

[MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) is a portable way to communicate between clusters of nodes. An MPI cluster can work across nodes.

> What does you can use the snow functionality mean? How should I do that?

`snow` is a separate package. To make a 16 node `MPI` cluster with snow, do `cl <- makeCluster(16, type = "MPI")` but you need to be running R in the right environment, as described Steve Weston's answer and [in his answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899756/initializing-mpi-cluster-with-snowfall-r). (Once you get it running you may also need to modify your loop to use 4 cores on each node.)

Comment: When I execute the command `makeCluster(16, type = "MPI")` the R session is terminated and I get a seg fault error (on the linux shell). Do you know how to fix that?